# How to convert istringstream object to string and char array?

Tags: c++, stream, istringstream

I have this object:

```
istringstream ob_stream;
```

I need to convert this object to string and char array for work. How to do?

Comment: `ob_stream.str()` returns an `std::string`, and you can invoke `c_str()` on the returned `std::string`

Comment: and how to do for object istream...example istream is_object; I need also convert to string and char array...

Comment: Make sure you create a separate string if you store the result of `c_str()`.

Comment: @user1779502, An `istream` contains no string until you read one.

Answer (score 5):

For a `std::string`:

`ob_stream.str();`

for a `char` array:

`ob_stream.str().c_str();`